# Changing background of custom WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I've got a custom ComboBox which should react to the value of some dependency properties. (e.g. validation).
Now, I just can't find out how to change the background of the combobox control in the triggers of the controltemplate... I can change the dropdown menu, but haven't yet found out how to change the background of the whole control. The dependency properties are set correctly, here's the XAML:

```xml
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border
              x:Name="Border" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              CornerRadius="2"
              Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="1" />
        <Border 
              Grid.Column="0"
              CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" 
              Margin="1" 
              Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" 
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
        <Path 
              x:Name="Arrow"
              Grid.Column="1"     
              Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />

</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type local:ErgoDentComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>-->
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ErgoDentComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton 
                        Name="ToggleButton" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                            Style="{x:Null}" 
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            Margin="3,3,23,3"
                            Focusable="True" 
                          Background="Transparent"
                            Visibility="Hidden"
                            IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup 
                            Name="Popup"
                            Placement="Bottom"
                            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                            AllowsTransparency="True" 
                            Focusable="False"
                            PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid 
                                  Name="DropDown"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
           Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!-- THIS ISN'T WORKING -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsValidationError" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGreen" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In the code of the control I can easily set the background, how would I do this in the triggers?

Thanks

Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still slightly confused as to what you really want to change. I'll assume it's the ToggleButton background.

Since you have a separate ControlTemplate for the ToggleButton, I suggest you work with `TemplateBinding`, if you want to pass the color from your ComboBox template trigger to the ToggleButton template. The same method would apply for changing the border color.

In your ComboBox Template:

```xml
<ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
              Grid.Column="2" Focusable="false" ClickMode="Press"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/> <!-- notice this line -->


 <Trigger Property="IsValidationError" Value="False">
     <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" /> <!-- changing dropdown background -->
     <Setter TargetName="ToggleButton" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" /> <!-- changing togglebutton background -->
 </Trigger>
```

In your ToggleButton Template:

```xml
 <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" Margin="1" 
         BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" /> <!-- notice this line -->
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to change more than just the button, but assuming I only wanted to change the button, how would I do this? I guess I don't really have to overwrite the whole ComboBox template, or? I think I've just not totally grasped the concepts of the template overriding completely...

Comment: No, in my answer, only the passages you need to change are included (watch for the "notice this line" comments). You can stick with your template. I also tested it, works for me.

Comment: Excellent, I managed to implement your solution, thank you very very much for taking your time... Actually this is really exactly what I wanted, I just don't seem to have expressed myself very well.

Comment: By the way, due to stackoverflow restrictions I only can award the bounty in 21 hours...

Comment: Glad to have helped. The communication difficulty was probably because you thought of the togglebutton as only the arrow part to the right, while it is actually also the part to the left (because when you click there, the dropdown also has to open).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try setting Background property for your ContentSite (content presenter as it is the one who shows combobox content). Otherwise a workaround idea - wrap the content presenter with a border and set is bacground.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, the contentpresenter has no Background property, and if I just put a border around it (with a background color), then I just get a rectangle instead of the control (with the defined background color...)

Answer (score 0):

The Background property will just change the edit and drop arrow area of a WPF Combobox.
To change other colors like popup background and highlight color, you have to add some brushes to the resource dictionary, mapping to the system colors:

```
var combo = new Combobox(); 
combo.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
combo.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
combo.Resources.Add(SystemColors.WindowBrushKey, Brushes.Yellow);
combo.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, Brushes.Red);

<Combobox Background="Yellow" Foreground="Blue">
   <Combobox.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
   </Combobox.Resources>
</Combobox>
```

resource :[a link] http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/84637/TIP-Change-background-of-WPF-Combobox

Comment: Changing the Edit and drop arrow area of the ComboBox actually would be exactly what I want to do... And especially I want to do this depending on a property in the ControlTemplate...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did...  Where you have your "ContentPresenter", I wrapped mine with a "border" and assigned IT a "name" value such as

```xml
<Border Name="presenterBorder"
    Background="White"
    BorderThickness="0"
    BorderBrush="Transparent"
    Margin="0"
    Grid.Column="0" >

    <ContentPresenter
        Name="ContentSite"
        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
        Margin="3,3,23,3"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Border>
```

Then, change your trigger... In my case, since I dont have the same property you had, I just simulated via "IsMouseOver".  I changed colors, but critical thing is "TargetName".  You want to change the background and border of the control named "presenterBorder" which is the border you've wrapped the text content presenter with.

```xml
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" TargetName="presenterBorder" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Maroon" TargetName="presenterBorder" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: This actually sounds right, however I get a white box instead of a ComboBox... Is my ComboBox Template maybe faulty in some way? I'm rather new to custom controls, actually I just want to overwrite the combobox template with the additional trigger...

Comment: @Daniel, If you look at my border, I explicitly put white, but you might just need to change that.  Let me know

Comment: Well, even any other color would seem to then overwrite the whole content... and if its transparent then I can't "color in" the stuff under it. I found a solution by changing the background of the ToggleButton. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Daniel, you can set the default background to transparent, then change it to your red, green, whatever in the trigger so you can get both the content area and your drop-down to show invalid representation.